# PHP memory limit with SQL result

Tags: php, sql

I'm facing a problem that shouldn't be hard at all to solve, but somehow I can't. Here is scenario:

I want to fetch results from SQL statement into PHP array, seems simple right?

The problem is that it gives me error about memory_limit (***Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 408944640) (tried to allocate 805306376 bytes)***).

Here is my code that is working with statements that gives less results (statement that I need to use contains +/- 4000 records).

```
$connect = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if($connect->connect_errno!=0)
{
    echo "Error: ".$connect->connect_errno."Why: ". $connect->connect_error;
}
else{
    $query = "SELECT meta_value, post_date 
FROM 
  wp_postmeta
  INNER JOIN 
  wp_posts
  ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
where wp_posts.post_type ='shop_order' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_order_total'";
    $sql_query=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    if ($sql_query->num_rows > 0){
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query))!== false){
        $result[] = $row;
    }} else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Not really sure why it's uses 0.8 GB of memory (seems pretty much for a simple statement. However to give it a try I have changed memory_limit in php.ini file to: **memory_limit=8192M**. But it didn't help at all (checked if memory_limit appiled calling php_info() function).

Thank you guys!

Comment: It is not the statement, it is the data from the table stored in array `$result[]`

Comment: Do you really need an `INNER JOIN` for this?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yeah, but the problem is with saving result from statement in multidimensional array

Comment: @Gobbin I think so, why?

Comment: Your mysqli_fetch_assoc is already an array. So why just not echo that and skip the while loop

Comment: Do you really need those 4000 rows at the same time?

Comment: Make sure that you declare `$result` at the start, also to check if storing the data makes any difference - comment out the line `$result[] = $row;` and see if it runs then.

Comment: What aim do you really want to achieve? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Gobbin Cause if I will skip while loop, I will get only 1 record instead of 4000.
@jarlh I need this whole array to pass into JavaScript to make a chart out of it, so I thought that it's the best way.

When I moved code from PHPStorm to XAMPP, it started to working, however `echo json_encode($result);` ain't showing result. When I have putted it into while loop it was showing results, but out of the loop it seems empty, will check it tho.

@Quasimodo'sclone I want to save results from SQL with PHP, then move em to JavaScript and show em on chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not hold full result tables in memory or your server will be vulnerable to DOS attacks easily. The server has to be able to reply to many requests simultaneously. Process only one row at once and release the allocated memory.

You should output the JSON chunks comma-seperated directly.

```
echo '[';

$sep = '';
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query))!== false){
    echo $sep . json_encode($row);
    $sep = ',';
}

echo ']';
```

Alternatively you could cache it in a temporary file.

On newer MySql versions you could try:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('meta_value', meta_value, 'post_date', post_date)
FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type ='shop_order' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_order_total' 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mysql-temp-GENERATED_UUID';
```

This generates a file with JSON lines, but not comma-seperated.
As documentated on [mysqlserverteam.com](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-from-sql-tables-to-json-documents-and-back-again/) the aggretage function `JSON_ARRAYAGG` should fix that. (My installation unfortunately has third party repository conflicts, thus I cannot test it.)

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAGG(JSON_OBJECT('meta_value', meta_value, 'post_date', post_date))
FROM wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type ='shop_order' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_order_total' 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mysql-temp-GENERATED_UUID';
```

If `JSON_ARRAYAGG` causes problems for some reason, a workaround (at least on unix-like systems) would be:

```
<?php
  $guid = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
  $tmp_filename = "/tmp/mysql-json-{$guid}.json";
  /* let MySql generate the tempfile, then */

  passthru('sed \'1 s/^/[/; $! s/$/,/ ; $ s/$/]/\' ' . $tmp_filename);
?>
```

Comment: result is `[{},{}{}]`

Comment: Yes, edited. Should sleep before coding on the fly. :)

Comment: No, `$sep` is the **prefix** which is set after the first iteration.

Comment: It's showing results, however it's working slow to load all results. Thinking if it's not the same case while saving data into array. Maybe there is just a better way to pass so "much" records to JavaScript. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: @Sinner Depending on your MySql version there is. `SELECT JSON_ARRAY(...)` / `SELECT JSON_OBJECT(...)` `INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/[some-random-uid].json'` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html / https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html Don't forget to remove the temporary file when done.

Comment: @Sinner When managed generating a tempfile from database system, you would use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to passthru the file to the output stream.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Will try this after I will do my test with AJAX, however I will test it :) Will let you know, when I will be done.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Trying to make a statement to fetch records into JSON, however don't know how to achieve this with `SELECT JSON_OBJECT, trying to mix it with my statement `SELECT meta_value, post_date
                   FROM
                   wp_postmeta
                   INNER JOIN
                   wp_posts
                   ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
                   where wp_posts.post_type ='shop_order' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_order_total' ` , however every attempt gives me SQL syntax error

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Whoa, thank you. Was trying pretty the same, but find out that I just have installed too old MySQL, ll have to update it. Also have one more idea that will test, however thank you for this solution, as long as my idea won't work I will use yours, since it seems like it should work :) Thank you buddy.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Wordpress to query and paginate like this:

```
$args = array(
    "post_type" => "shop_order",
    "posts_per_page" => 1000,
    "post_status" => array("any"),
    "paged" => $paged, // pass your pagination here from javascript
    "meta_query" => array(
        "key" => "_order_total",
        "compare" => "EXISTS"
    )
);
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);

echo json_encode($custom_posts);
```

Comment: The user needs the result to create a chart. Paginating the result is not what he needs.

Comment: I just need an simple application to analyse data and show em on charts, so there is no point to use wordpress I think.

Comment: Sure it is. He's OOM. Paginating will allow him to execute his query in chunks without running out of memory.

Comment: I would then use ajax or the API to make the queries and populate your chart. This would allow you to process infinite amount of records without running out of memory.

Comment: @TimHallman That might be a good idea, I might try it, but have to read more about AJAX and API solution.

Comment: @TimHallman Wrote it in AJAX, but it doesn't give response with so much records. It works great with table that has less records (tested on 140).